# Is it possible to create wireshark/tcpdump from netcat?

Tags: linux, unix, wireshark, tcpdump, netcat

I've got one question. Is it possible to create wireshark/tcpdump from netcat? I mean,if you can use, for example, flags or series of commands combined with netcat to get the same / similar monitoring results as tcpdump / wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because `netcat` cannot eavesdrop on existing connections.

`tcpdump` and `wireshark` get access to all packets that go through a network device. `netcat` cannot possibly do that.

Comment: Maxim, thanks for your answer. So, how can i get the largest piece of information, just similar to tcpdump, using netcat(or netcat+other program excluded wireshark and tcpdump)? It is important for me. Is there any chance to do it?(just similar).

Comment: @johnpanda1 No chance.